# Is 長生きはするもんな a set phrase?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Is 長生きはするもんだな a set phrase meaning "you live and learn"?

Comment: Isn't it 「長生きはするもん**だ**な」?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking. But you're right, I misremembered what I read. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set phrase variations are:

「長生{ながい}きはするもん**だな**。」

「長生きはするもん**だね**。」

「長生きはするもん**ですね**。」

「長生きはするもん**だよね**。」

etc.

We do ***not*** say 「長生きはするもん**な**。」← This is the one in the title.

Comment: 長生きはするもんな could mean "(but) he/she/it/they do live long", as in 「金魚は死にやすいけど、長生きはするもんな」 and, yes, it differs a lot from 長生きはするもん**だ**な.